# Possible to give custom names when instantiating multiple sub_block instances?

Tags: origen-sdk

I was using this [doc guide](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/models/defining/#Wash,_Rinse,_Repeat) to instantiate multiple instances of an IP block.

```
sub_blocks :core_pll, class_name: 'CORE_PLL', instances: 7
```

When I check the sub_blocks in the DUT model I see that Origen increments from 0-6 in the name of the instances.  Is there a way to provide a list of custom names to override the numbering?  I know I can just instantiate each separately, just wondering if there was another way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently.

This is one possibility using native Ruby features which is not too bad:

```rb
sub_blocks :core_pll, class_name: 'CORE_PLL', instances: 7
# Aliases for the PLL blocks...
def plla; core_pll0; end
def pllb; core_pll1; end
def pllc; core_pll2; end
#...
```

Then you can use the alternative method accessor names:

```rb
dut.pllb == dut.core_pll1    # => true
```

Note that due to the way that the accessor method is not generated until you first access it, you can't do this unfortunately:

```rb
alias :pllb :core_pll1
```

Obviously something to support this could be built into the `sub_block` API in future if you think it is worth it.